# how to preview images in multiple input type "file"-s

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have this code:

```js
const chosenImage = document.getElementById('chosen_image')

for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]')) {
  input.onchange = (e) => {


    if (e.target.files.length) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      console.log(e.target.nextElementSibling);
      // do stuff
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      reader.onload = () => {
        chosenImage.setAttribute("src", reader.result);
        e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent = e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent.replace(/False/, input.files[0].name)
      }

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section_header">
  <figure class="uploaded_image_container">
    <img id="chosen_image">
  </figure>
  <div class="upload_section_outer">
    <h6>Text U:</h6>
    <div class="upload_section">
      <button id="performance_img_20" onclick="document.getElementById('img_20').click()">Upload image</button>
      <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/svg" id='img_20' style="display:none">
      <label>Upload complete: False</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section_header">
  <figure class="uploaded_image_container">
    <img id="chosen_image">
  </figure>
  <div class="upload_section_outer">
    <h6>Text U:</h6>
    <div class="upload_section">
      <button id="performance_img_21" onclick="document.getElementById('img_21').click()">Upload image</button>
      <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/svg" id='img_21' style="display:none">
      <label>Upload complete: False</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section_header">
  <figure class="uploaded_image_container">
    <img id="chosen_image">
  </figure>
  <div class="upload_section_outer">
    <h6>Text U:</h6>
    <div class="upload_section">
      <button id="performance_img_19" onclick="document.getElementById('img_19').click()">Upload image</button>
      <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/svg" id='img_19' style="display:none">
      <label>Upload complete: False</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem is that it previews only on the first section, but I need to display on every individually for each upload. Additionally the text only changes for the first uploaded image and I have no clue why. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get here is the first chosen_image element, not the second or even the third.

```js
const chosenImage = document.getElementById('chosen_image'); 
//...
chosenImage.setAttribute("src", reader.result);
//...
```

It is recommended to use class, So it can be

```js
const chosenImage = document.getElementsByClassName('chosen_image')
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]');
for(let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
  input = inputs[i];
  input.onchange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files.length) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      console.log(e.target.nextElementSibling);
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
      reader.onload = () => {
        chosenImage[i].setAttribute("src", reader.result);
        e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent = e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent.replace(/False/, e.target.files[0].name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqPWY.png)

---

but use for of(it is previewing in the following div ad not in the one the button is pushed)

```js
const chosenImage = document.getElementsByClassName('chosen_image')

let i = 0;
for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]')) {
  input.onchange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files.length) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      console.log(e.target.nextElementSibling);
      // do stuff
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      reader.onload = () => {
        chosenImage[i].setAttribute("src", reader.result); //edit here
        e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent = e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent.replace(/False/, input.files[0].name)
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code has a typo: it's `getElementsByClassName()` (not getElementsByClass). I strongly recommend adding a working snippet to prove your code is working.

Comment: It is giving me an error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')
    at FileReader.reader.onload

Comment: @Nicik The problem has been changed, i++ is placed in the condition

Comment: this works but there is one bug, it is previewing in the following div ad not in the one the button is pushed.

Comment: @Nicik Sorry,That's right.This seems to be a for...of problem, or an onchange problem, I am also a little confused; but it is normal now

Comment: @RorinL no proble, thanks for the help anyway. I just deleted and rewrote the whole function. works the way I needed it.